# VBScript Printer Driver Install throws WMI Error -2146500025

Tags: windows, printing, vbscript, driver, wmi

I'm trying to install a printer driver using WMI and a VBScript but I keep getting the error code 2146500025 from the WMI AddPrinterDriver function.

What am I doing wrong? I need to install 2 drivers (1 Dell and 1 Lexmark) and both instances return the same error code. The drivers are signed and the .cat file is present with the .inf. The certificates are also valid (Expires late 2016)

```
Set objDriver = oWmi.Get("Win32_PrinterDriver")
objDriver.Name = DRIVERNAME
objDriver.SupportedPlatform = "Windows NT x86"
objDriver.Version = "3" 'Win2K
objDriver.FilePath = "c:\drivers\printers\Lexmark_Universal_PS"
objDriver.InfName = "c:\drivers\printers\Lexmark_Universal_PS\LMUD1n40.inf"
wmiResult = objDriver.AddPrinterDriver(objDriver)
If wmiResult<>0 Then
    wscript.echo "WMI " & wmiResult
End If  
If Err.Number<>0 Then
    wscript.echo Err.Description
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that the files were tampered with prior to me receiving them. This in turn broke the signatures and prevented the drivers from installing successfully.